# Save data from diffrent partial views on Single view on single button submit in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have three classes

```
  public partial class User
{          
    public string No_ { get; set; }      
    public string LastName { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Education> Educations { get; set; }
} 
public partial class Education
{
    public string No_ { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public string Institution { get; set; }
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
}
public partial class Login
{        
    public string No_ { get; set; }     
    public string UserId { get; set; }       
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

i have made three partial views for three diffrent models and made it render into a page as below

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/BlankLayout.cshtml";
 }
 <h2>
Register</h2>@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
      @Html.Partial("LoginPartialView")

      @Html.Partial("UserPartialView")

      @Html.Partial("ProfessionPartialView")

      <section>
          <div>
             <button class="reset">Reset</button>
             <button class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
   </section>
}
```

what i want is when i click the submit button all the data from the partial views should get to [httppost] where i can save the data to User,Education,Login Tables . how to get the data into the controller which has http post controller like :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(?,?,?)
    {
        context.Logins.Add(LoginObject);
        context.Educations.Add(EducationObject);
        context.Professions.Add(ProfessionObject);
        return View();
    }
```

i just want to know how to get the above partial views data into the httppost controller so that i can save the data as mentioned above

i am pretty much novice in Mvc 3 Pardon me if i am making no sense while i am asking . please guide me along with

Comment: What are the models you use in each of those partial views?

Comment: @Eranga i used Login , Profession , Education model for each of them ... to be used in partial views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of partials I would recommend you using editor templates. Here's an example how you could write a form that will save the User object:

```
@model User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/BlankLayout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
Register</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.No_)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Logins)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Educations)

    <section>
        <div>
            <button class="reset">Reset</button>
            <button class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
   </section>
}
```

and then the 2 corresponding editor templates:

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Login.cshtml`:

```
@model Login
... some input fields for the login
```

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Education.cshtml`:

```
@model Education
... some input fields for the education
```

and the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(User model)
{
    // the model object will be correctly populated from the default model binder
    // here we can save it
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: thats a nice solution . but can want to ask a small thing .1st is that User( which you have created ) is a ViewModel ? and 2nd  how can we on fly declare the runtime scaffolding for the editor template for login , Education , User ? is there any way out so that we can on the fly can turn on and off the scaffolding options for the model Attributes while viewing the editing options in diffrent pages ?

Comment: @Joy, oh, sorry I never used scaffolding and have no idea how it works. I prefer defining my own view models and views.

Comment: NP , i would check it out and revert back then. though i guess viewmodel might solve my issue for time being . but i was really looking if scaffolding could solve my problem . instead of creating my own views . may be there should exist an option too if in case we can do  that as wel so we can use the ViewModel + EditorTemplates = On Fly Reusable Templates for custom Models :)

Comment: ..well i tried for the editor templates couldnt just get hooked upto it how the custom editor templates for custom model objects should look. can you just provide me an example with a custom editor template which you havent given **~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Education.cshtml:**  ??? i just wanna look how does it be made actually